# Is there a RPM package for GCC 6.2 for Cent OS 7.2 ? Looks there is only source. I am trying to compile and it is running hours ? any idea

Tags: gcc, rpm, centos7

Is there a RPM package for GCC 6.2 for Cent OS 7.2 ? Looks there is only source. I am trying to compile and it is running for hours. Any idea how long will it take to build the binaries ?

Comment: Check the devtoolset packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around a little on [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3); but it seems like there is no gcc 6.2 for centos7 available.

I am not quite astonished; since centos wants to build an os that has a long time support; they will never take the latest version; but keep some older versions that have proven to be stable.

Comment: that means we have to compile the source or is it not at all supported ?

Comment: I think it will work if you recompile from source. It has not been done yet however (at least not published). Normally you should use rpms with "el7" in their name (don't really know what that means exactly). I have succesfully rebuilt some opensuse rpms and installed them on centos5; so probably that might work (but you might need to change the spec file a little to make it work)

Comment: I tried compiling, and it took more than 3 hrs on a centos 7.2 VM. I was sucessfull on the second attempt.

Comment: @KrishSanj : congrats. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it so other people see that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [devtoolset](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/). This links to 4, but their yum repo seems to have a "devtool-6" that has GCC6. I thought the main page explaining the project, etc, would be more useful. It is installed into an alternate path so you run a script that sets things up for you.